# Как настроить location в Nginx для скачивания файлов

Tags: nginx, download, location

В конфигурации Nginx имеется location /download/ - соответствует /etc/nginx/data/download
В ней находятся файлы File1.txt и File2.txt.

Как описать секцию location, чтобы при обращении
[http://127.0.0.1/download/File1.txt\](http://127.0.0.1/download/File1.txt%5C)
или

http://127.0.0.1/download/FILE.txt

или

http://127.0.0.1/download/file1.txt

Файл File1.txt скачивался вне зависимости от того какими буквами (ЗАГЛАВНЫЕ/прописные) указано имя файла.

Нюанс - при обращении http://127.0.0.1/download/ список файлов не должен отображаться (autoindex on исключается).
Если указывать имя в виде FILE.txt или file1.TXT скачивания не происходит - ошибка.
Пример части config:

```
Location ~* /download {

root /etc/nginx/data

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: нужно файлы на диске привести к нижнему регистру. написать фильтр чтоб в урл привелось к нижнему